# Writing BSON to disk

Tags: python, bson

I'm storing hierarchical data in a format similar to JSON:

```
{
    "preferences": {
       "is_latest": true,
       "revision": 18,
       // ...
    },
    "updates": [
       { "id": 1, "content": "..." },
       // ...
    ]
}
```

I'm writing this data to disk and I'd like to store it efficiently. I assume that, towards this end, BSON would be more efficient as a storage format than raw JSON.

How can I read and write BSON trees to/from disk in Python?

Comment: The first couple of hits when you google "python bson" give you what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but it looks like there is a bson module on PyPI:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson

The project is hosted in GitHub here:
https://github.com/martinkou/bson